# Problems with showing prev and next content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need help in my script. I am trying to make prev and next
What I need is I want to limit content. 5 div only inside ul tag if it reaches 5 div then it moves others to next.

Like I want to limit 5 div per show to move on next div or content. So the main point is showing content inside ul tag limited by 5 div's only and then show others next

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
     <ul id="1">
     <li>
     
    <div>    
    <p>This is the text 1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 2</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 3</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 4</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 5</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 6</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 7</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>This is the text 8</p>
    </div>
     
     </li>

    <div class="bottom">
        <p>showing 1 of 1</p>
        <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
    </div>
    
                                                            
    </ul>
                                    
    
    </div>
    
    <script>
    
    var current = 1;
    
    // function to go to previous
    var prev = function() {
        current -= 1;
        if (current < 1) current = 1; // can't go too far previous
        showContent();
    };
    
    // function to go next
    var next = function() {
        current += 1; 
        showContent(); //can't go too far next
    };
    
    // Update what content we are showing based on the "current" index
    var showContent = function() {
        var display;
    };
    
    // bind the prev and next function to the links 
    document.getElementById('prev').onclick = prev;
    document.getElementById('next').onclick = next;
    
    // Setup the initial state of the content
    showContent();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just a remark the only direct child on `ul` element should be `li` element.
see : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

Comment: @A.RAZIK i have edited it and put </li>

Comment: what I meant is you need to change the divs into il elements or just wrap your divs inside li element to have a correct html

Comment: If you want to automate the process of adding _items_ to your `<ul>` list so that you have a series of `<ul>` tags that each holding 5 items, you need to write a script and define a function for adding _items_ and then within that function, you can check whether the `<ul>` tags capacity is full or not, if it was full, you add it to the next. Did I get your question right?

Comment: You should create your elements inside your javascript if you want to control them dynamically, it's a better approach!

Comment: i will be happy if you can show me a bit example of code, thats why i posted here for help

Comment: If this is a static html page, you need to use javascript to either add the desired divs, or use it to remove undesired divs. However, this is a situation that a template engine such as ejs would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this from your code, give it a try and let me know is it good for you. Obviously it needs a lot of improvements, but you missed some important things to do the pagination like how much you want to see on a page `itemsPerPage`, and calculating the number of pages `numberOfPages` so that you can limit click on next link. And subtracting the items that you want to see in a page is done via `Array.slice(startIndex, endIndex)` and then getting the difference between all items in the `ul` and the sliced part, then control either show them or not via adding and removing predefined extra css classes `.show` and `.hide`. Finally, adding two `span` elements (`.current-page` and `number-of-pages`) to visualize pagination infos.

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id="1">
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 3</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 5</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 6</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 7</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 8</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 9</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 10</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 11</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 12</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 13</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 14</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 15</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>This is the text 16</p>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <div class="bottom">
      <p>showing <span class="current-page"></span> of <span class="number-of-pages"></span></p>
        <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var lis = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
        var itemsPerPage = 5;
        var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(lis.length/itemsPerPage);
        var current = 0;
        
        document.querySelector(".number-of-pages").innerHTML = numberOfPages;
        var cp = document.querySelector(".current-page");
        cp.innerHTML = current+1;
        
        // function to go to previous
        var prev = function() {
            if (current === 0){return;} // can't go too far previous
          current--;
          var res = Array.from(lis).slice((current*itemsPerPage), (current+1)*itemsPerPage);
            res.forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("show");
            e.classList.remove("hide");
          });
          Array.from(lis).filter(e=>!Array.from(res).includes(e)).forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("hide");
            e.classList.remove("show");
          });
          cp.innerHTML = current+1;
        };

        // function to go next
        var next = function() {
            if (current+1 === numberOfPages){return;} // can't go too far previous
          current++;
          var res = Array.from(lis).slice(current*itemsPerPage, (current+1)*itemsPerPage);
          res.forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("show");
            e.classList.remove("hide");
          });
          Array.from(lis).filter(e=>!Array.from(res).includes(e)).forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("hide");
            e.classList.remove("show");
          });
          cp.innerHTML = current+1;
        };

        // Update what content we are showing based on the "current" index
        var showContent = function() {
          var res = Array.from(lis).slice(current*itemsPerPage, (current+1)*itemsPerPage);
          res.forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("show");
          });
          Array.from(lis).filter(e=>!Array.from(res).includes(e)).forEach(e=>{
            e.classList.add("hide");
          });
        };

        // bind the prev and next function to the links 
        document.getElementById('prev').onclick = prev;
        document.getElementById('next').onclick = next;

        // Setup the initial state of the content
        showContent();
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```